# expected expression before do. macro using do while loop

Tags: c, macros

I have implemented my custom sizeof operator as below

```
#define my_sizeof(x) do{\
    typeof(x) _a;\
    (char*)(&_a + 1) - (char*)(&_a);\
}while(0)
```

If I compile it I get the error

```
test.c:26:22: error: expected expression before ‘do’
```

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

My main function is given below.

```
int main()
{
   int a;

   unsigned long long b;
   double c;

   printf("size of a %zd \n",my_sizeof(a));
   printf("size of b %zd \n",my_sizeof(b));
   printf("size of c %zd \n",my_sizeof(c));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does the code using the macro look like?

Comment: @CristiFati - Please see comments above.

Comment: I would assume the problem is that your operator is cannot be evaluated to a value. You defined a macro, so it means the preprocessor simply pushes all that 'do while' loop as a parameter to printf, and its not legal

Comment: Macros are being executed by the preprocessor which treats them as text (before the compiler comes into play), so your `printf` line(s) would look something like `printf("size of a %zd \n", do{typeof......`

Comment: What's wrong with the regular `sizeof` operator, anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Your macro expands to a `do` loop.  A `do` loop is not an expression, and does not produce a value.  The compiler is telling you that you cannot use a `do` loop where you are trying to use one, and it is right.

There is no clean alternative in C, since you cannot declare a variable inside an expression.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the way you macro is preprocessed. The preprocessor output (which you may get using `gcc -E file.c`) will look like this (stripped for `a` variable only):

```
int main() {
    int a;
    printf("size of a %zd \n", do { typeof(a) _a; (char*)(&_a + 1) - (char*)(&_a); } while (0));
    return 0;
}
```

which is not a correct C syntax. You could use `do..while` macro like that though (without an assignment or nesting it inside another function):

```
MY_MACRO(x);
```

Refer to [this article](http://pilt.github.io/2009/10/16/the-use-of-do-while-0-in-c-macros/) for some more information.

Answer (score 1):

A do/while loop can't return a value. You could instead use a GCC-style [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) to do what you're trying:

```
#define my_sizeof(x) ({              \
    typeof(x) _a;                    \
    (char*)(&_a + 1) - (char*)(&_a); \
})
```

Clang & GCC support statement expressions for sure, I don't know about any other compilers off the top of my head.